# Oracle select and update periodically records

Tags: sql

I have a table that includes multiple records duplicated status values.

> ```
> DEVICE    STATUS     CHANGE_DATE
> 1     1       21.11.2017 12:01
> 1     0       21.11.2017 13:05
> 1     1       21.11.2017 14:06
> 1     0       21.11.2017 14:26
> 1     1       21.11.2017 14:36
> 2     0       21.11.2017 15:28
> 2     1       21.11.2017 15:39
> ```

Device status change priodically.

1. First question is, I want to select by device id last status is 1.

Query result will be like this;

> ```
> DEVICE    STATUS     CHANGE_DATE
> 1        1    21.11.2017 14:36
> 2        1    21.11.2017 15:39
> ```

1. The second query is about update for same result. If data comes like this:

> ```
> DEVICE    STATUS     CHANGE_DATE
> 1        1       11.11.2017 12:36
> 1        1       21.11.2017 14:36
> 2        1       21.11.2017 15:39
> ```

Device 1 is an old date. And I want to update a record is older 2 days.

How can I create these oracle queries? Select and update older records.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Postgresql?

Comment: What have tried? Show us your current query attempts.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to close the question as too broad.  But, I'll answer the first part:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by device order by change_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I think the "update" should be a separate question.